# perl - search multi-line string for match of any of a list of strings

Tags: perl

I have a list of bug identifiers.

For each bugid in this buglist, I run an external command to get the history of the bug as a multi-line string:

```
$buginfo = `dumpbug $bugid`;
```

`$buginfo` looks something like this (greatly simplified):

```
04/04/2014     dog     created
04/04/2014     cat     manager
04/04/2014     moose   assigner
04/04/2014     moose   engineer
04/05/2014     moose   resolved
04/06/2014     rabbit  verified
```

Now I want to see if any of (fox, aardvark, emu, rabbit) has ever had anything to do with this bug.

I would like to stop searching through `$bugid` on the first match of any user in my list.

I will be searching the buginfo from each of the bugids in my buglist for the same users.

I am also limited to features of perl 5.8

Comment: Can you not get the result of the multi-line string into an array: `@buginfo = ...;`? Then you could just iterate over the elemnts of the array with a `foreach`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print "$1 was involved in bug $bugid.\n" if $buginfo =~ /\b(fox|aardvark|emu|rabbit)\b/;
```

Comment: That regex will also match `lemur`, for example.